# Installation of FluentBit failing at make stage

Tags: cmake, centos, fluentd, fluent-bit

I'm trying to install FluentBit on Centos.

While running make it fails at 83% and I'm unable to understand the error. Cannot find anything in the web relating to this. Can someone please help me.

```
[ 83%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/fluent-bit-bin.dir/fluent-bit.c.o
[ 83%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/fluent-bit-bin.dir/flb_dump.c.o
Linking C executable ../bin/fluent-bit
../library/libflb-plugin-filter_grep.a(grep.c.o): In function `delete_rules':
grep.c:(.text+0x4e3): undefined reference to `flb_ra_destroy'
../library/libflb-plugin-filter_grep.a(grep.c.o): In function `set_rules':
grep.c:(.text+0x861): undefined reference to `flb_ra_create'
../library/libflb-plugin-filter_grep.a(grep.c.o): In function `grep_filter_data':
grep.c:(.text+0xa6a): undefined reference to `flb_ra_regex_match'
../library/libflb-plugin-filter_rewrite_tag.a(rewrite_tag.c.o): In function `process_config':
rewrite_tag.c:(.text+0x9b5): undefined reference to `flb_ra_create'
rewrite_tag.c:(.text+0xa9c): undefined reference to `flb_ra_destroy'
rewrite_tag.c:(.text+0xade): undefined reference to `flb_ra_create'
rewrite_tag.c:(.text+0xb3b): undefined reference to `flb_ra_destroy'
../library/libflb-plugin-filter_rewrite_tag.a(rewrite_tag.c.o): In function `process_record':
rewrite_tag.c:(.text+0xf6a): undefined reference to `flb_ra_regex_match'
rewrite_tag.c:(.text+0xfe2): undefined reference to `flb_ra_translate'
../library/libflb-plugin-filter_rewrite_tag.a(rewrite_tag.c.o): In function `destroy_rules':
rewrite_tag.c:(.text+0x12a3): undefined reference to `flb_ra_destroy'
rewrite_tag.c:(.text+0x12b3): undefined reference to `flb_ra_destroy'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [bin/fluent-bit] Error 1
make[1]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/fluent-bit-bin.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Did you resolve it ?

Comment: @Makubex I re-did everything using CentOs AMI instead of the AWS ECS optimised Linux AMI. The installation worked out flawlessly. AWS ami's....no no